# Как убрать выделение ранее выбранного элемента в ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в ListView отключить или убирать выделение ранее выбранного элемента списка? Что бы не было так, как на изображении.
[image: пример]
В идеале оставить только подсветку элемента, при наведении курсора мыши. (что я и получаю, когда добавляю в стили : `<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>`)
Но после этого, при нажатии на элемент списка - ничего не происходит(`SelectionChanged="ListView2_SelectionChanged"` - не работает), хотя визуально - всё отлично!

Буду рад Вашему совету!
Спасибо!

Comment: Перепишите полностью стиль Item'a и задайте ему нужный триггер при наведении мыши.

Comment: Я был бы очень Вам признателен, за помощь или ссылку. Второй день я пытаюсь решить проблему, но всё никак не могу продвинуться :(

Comment: Стоп, вам надо просто убрать выделение 2-ого элемента? Если да, то просто установите `SelectionMode="Single"`.

Comment: Нет, мне необходимо убрать выделение вообще. Визуально. Что бы не было того, что на изображении в зелёном квадрате. Там строка 002 - это оставшийся фокус, после нажатия но строку. А на 004 - наведён курсор. Убрать я пытаюсь то, что на строке 002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> мне необходимо убрать выделение вообще. Визуально.

Как я и говорил, для таких целей просто переопределите стиль элемента.

Допустим у нас есть стандартный `ListView` с некоторыми элементами:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.Items>
        <sys:String>1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>3</sys:String>
        <sys:String>4</sys:String>
        <sys:String>5</sys:String>
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

Делаем стиль для `ListViewItem` в котором убираем полностью визуальный эффект выделения, но оставляем реагирование на наведенную мышь:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="panel">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="panel" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Тут по сути все просто:

- Сам стиль применяется ко всем объектам типа `ListViewItem`. Если нужно на некоторых, то задаем `x:Key` и нужному `ListView` указываем `ItemContainerStyle`.
- Стиль переопределяет шаблон одного Item'a (`<Setter Property="Template">`) на указанный нами. А указываем мы простую `StackPanel` с одним текстовым контролом.
- Далее в  `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` мы указываем необходимые триггеры этого шаблона. В нашем случае это всего один триггер, который меняет цвет у `StackPanel` на серый при наведении мыши.

Запускаем и смотрим на результат:

[image: Result]

Как видим при наведении мыши у нас успешно меняется цвет, при клике на объект выделение (визуально) не происходит.

Ну вот собственно и все.
Дальше вам остается подстроить под себя сам дизайн, ну и добавить может еще какие то триггеры.
Например добавим выделение, пусть при клике на объект он выделяется определенным цветом. Для этого сделаем еще один триггер:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="panel" Property="Background" Value="Lime"/>
</Trigger>
```

Результат:

[image: Result Selection]

Comment: Евгений, спасибо Вам за развёрнутый ответ! Да это именно то, что мне требовалось! Получилось аналог  `<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>` только выбор работает! УРА!!! Но только проявился нюанс. Если я, допустим, кликаю на первом элементе списка, происходит событие, то при повторном нажатии на этот же элемент - события уже не происходит :(  `ListView1.UnselectAll();` вроде бы должен решить проблему, но вылетает исключение "Индекс за пределами диапазона" в этой строке `select = (ClassName)ListView1.SelectedItems[0];`

Comment: `события уже не происходит` - правильно, потому что элемент уже выделен. Вы уверены, что вам нужен ListView? Что то мне кажется, что он не очень подходит под ваши задачи. Я бы на вашем месте создал простой ItemsControl, у которого нету выделения и чего либо еще, у него переопределил бы шаблон итема, задав ему обычный Button, который привязал бы к команде. Но в таком варианте вы не получите табличный вид. `ListView1.SelectedItems[0]` - у вас мульти выбор? Если нет, то тут достаточно `.SelectedItem`. И да, очень советую научится работать с привязками и забыть про обращение к элементам через имя!

Comment: Попробую поискать статью или примеры, где описана работа с привязками. Да бы лучше понять их и научиться работать с ними. Вижу их часто в примерах, но понимаю пока слабо. (c# я занимаюсь не так давно) Если Вам попадался хороший ресурс с описанием привязок, буду рад и благодарен за ссылку на него! Мульти выбора у меня нет, и я переписал на `.SelectedItem` . По поводу создания своего контрола - как вариант, но мне надо в строке разместить много элементов, текста, кнопок... думаю для меня это будет сложно на моём уровне развития.